# Access parent scope inside child element's onclick callback (Atom Package)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm not sure how you're normally supposed to handle this within Atom Packages, but this is the situation:

I created a beautiful button

```
playButton = document.createElement('button');
playButton.onclick = @funkyFreshCallback;
```

This will call my callback defined as so

```
  funkyFreshCallback: (event, element) ->
    console.log(@);
```

Now, what I want is to be able to use the element's parent scope.
See the **@** symbol? Right now it returns the button element (because that's the current *this*, I know)

Now how do I access the scope instead? The same one that defined *funkyFreshCallback*?

Also, it really doesn't feel like this is how I **should** be doing things but I haven't found much documentation... at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the parent context onto the function before setting it up as the event handler.

```
playButton.onclick = @funkyFreshCallback.bind(@);
```

---

**Another way** to avoid the context issue is to setup a function that calls `funkyFreshCallback`. The event handler should only *handle the event* and then pass along the minimum set of required data to the callback, like so:

```
playButton.onclick = (event, element) =>
    timePressed = Date.now();
    @funkyFreshCallback(timePressed);
```

With the code above, funkyFreshCallback will be called with the context that you expect, and won't receive a really complex event object as an argument. This helps to make writing unit tests for `funkyFreshCallback` easier, and it should simplify your callbacks, because they won't have to deal with events.

More on that in [Chapter 7 of Maintainable JavaScript](https://books.google.com/books?id=J5RCV8yM7sEC&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=Nick+Zakas+event+handlers&source=bl&ots=TEXCCBdVDu&sig=W2QSviiG7vvUsiKoofN2DqRrOTA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBWoVChMI0byG4rCOyQIVB5WICh2-jAVF#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Yup, this is a pretty typical use case for it when setting up event listeners that are often called with a global context.

Comment: Edited to include an alternate solution and explanation

Comment: Nice one, seems more readable to me as well. Though I guess that boils down to opinion.